# Codeigniter --- checkbox array issue

Tags: codeigniter

stuck in codeigniter code, checkbox array,

view code :

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="company_type[]" value="Exporter" class="get_value"> Exporter

  <input type="checkbox" name="company_type[]" value="Importer" class="get_value"> Importer

  <input type="checkbox" name="company_type[]" value="Distributor" class="get_value"> Distributor

  <?php
  foreach($form as $company_type)
  {
      echo $company_type = implode(",",$company_type);
  }

  ?>
```

=================================
model method:

```
  public function save_registration_form($post)
  {
  return $this->db->insert('members', [     'company_type'  =>$post['company_type']]);
  }
```

===========================================
controller code :

```
  if ($this->form_validation->run() ) {
  $this->model->form ($this->input->post() ) ;
```

==========================
code showing problem, please help to solve this

Answer (score 1):

You have to chagne your code like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="company_type[]" value="Exporter" class="get_value"> Exporter

<input type="checkbox" name="company_type[]" value="Importer" class="get_value"> Importer

<input type="checkbox" name="company_type[]" value="Distributor" class="get_value"> Distributor
```

> Model Code

```
public function save_registration_form($post){

        $company_type = implode(",",$post['company_type']);
        return $this->db->insert('members', ['company_type'  =>$company_type]);

  }
```